# The Video File Recorded by OBS Cannot Be Played by "Movie & TV" App

Tags: video

The OBS's *Recording* settings in *Output* are:

1. **Type:** Standard
2. **Recording Format:** mkv
3. **Encoder:** NVIDIA NVENC H.264(new)
4. **Rate Control:** Lossless
5. **Keyframe Interval:** 0
6. **Preset:** Max Quality
7. **Profile:** high [Look-ahead and Psycho Visual Tuning are checked]
8. **GPU:** 0
9. **Max B-Frame:** 4

The OBS's *Video* settings in *Advanced* are:

1. **Renderer:** Direct3D 11
2. **Color Format:** I444
3. **Color Space:** 709
4. **Color Range:** Full

Using the settings, OBS can record Windows Desktop in very high quality. However, the MKV file cannot be played by "Movie & TV" app or DivX Player.

OBS will remux the MKV file to MP4, the MP4 file cannot be played by "Movie & TV" app or DivX Pro either. But the MP4 file can be played by Chrome or Edge browser. MKV and MP4 are just containers to store video data, so I think the real problem should be in video data.

How can I record lossless video of Windows Desktop with OBS?

P.S. I have tried to use x264 with CRF 0 to record lossless video, but get the same result.

Comment: The OBS Studio version is *27.1.3*, and NVIDIA Driver version is *472.47*.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your comments content there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is exactly that you try encoding lossless H.264 video, or more correct your problem is decoding it. And lossless H.264 can be only encoded in "High 4:4:4 Predictive" profile while most of hardware H.264 decoders support only "High" profile (4:2:0) at max. Also not all software H.264 decoders support such profiles so I would recommend you to install LAVFilters which is based on ffmpeg and support almost all H.264 profiles.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I know why the video file cannot be played.

I try to use command line to transcode yuvj444p to yuv420p and yuvj420p:
`ffmpeg.exe -i yuvj444p.mp4 -pix_fmt yuv420p yuv420p.mp4` and `ffmpeg.exe -i yuvj444p.mp4 -pix_fmt yuvj420p yuvj420p.mp4`
yuv420p.mp4 and yuvj420p.mp4 can be played, but their color are not accurate, while screenshot with yuvj420p can display color accurately.

Is it possible to record Windows Desktop in yuvj420p or yuv420p with lossless video quality?

Comment: yuv420p/yuvj420p are subsampled 4:2:0 YUV colorspace where chroma planes are 1/4 size of luma plane. It can look good for real life photos but imho not so good (and sure not with lossless video quality) for Windows Desktop records with 1 pixel width lines, sharp edges and bitmap text.

Comment: I have notice that High 4:4:4 Predictive is part of H.264 profile, but may be supported by common player.
Here are some references:
[Need Video Editors for H.264 I444 (High 4:4:4 Predictive)](https://obsproject.com/forum/threads/need-video-editors-for-h-264-i444-high-4-4-4-predictive.118957/)
[H.264 profiles and levels](http://blog.mediacoderhq.com/h264-profiles-and-levels/)

The lossless video can be played by ffplay.exe.